# How to change color of square lines that make up the svg fence?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to add color to the **square lines** that make up the fence.

The lines of the fence currently have no color, I wanted to add color to it.

How do I do that?

That is all I am doing in the code.

How would that be done?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/bx3qse0z/

svg code:

```
 background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h10v10H0z"/><path d="M10 .15L5.15 5 10 9.85V10h-.13L5.01 5.14.15 10H0v-.14L4.87 5 0 .13V0h.15l4.86 4.86L9.86 0H10z"/></svg>');
}
```

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtain {
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  max-width: 642px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0px #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h10v10H0z"/><path d="M10 .15L5.15 5 10 9.85V10h-.13L5.01 5.14.15 10H0v-.14L4.87 5 0 .13V0h.15l4.86 4.86L9.86 0H10z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
 <div class="outer">
   <div class="curtain ">
     <div class="ratio-keeper">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add color to the fence"? Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add color to the square lines that make up the fence.

Comment: The lines of the fence currently have no color, I wanted to add color to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines on the fence are coming from the second `<path>` element in the SVG background image. Adding `stroke="COLOR_OF_CHOICE"` will give the color you want. Right now it appears black because the default stroke is `#000#`.

For example, if you want your fence to look green, then do this:

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><path d="M10 .15L5.15 5 10 9.85V10h-.13L5.01 5.14.15 10H0v-.14L4.87 5 0 .13V0h.15l4.86 4.86L9.86 0H10z" stroke="green"/></svg>');
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtain {
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  max-width: 642px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0px #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><path d="M10 .15L5.15 5 10 9.85V10h-.13L5.01 5.14.15 10H0v-.14L4.87 5 0 .13V0h.15l4.86 4.86L9.86 0H10z" stroke="green"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="curtain ">
     <div class="ratio-keeper">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```